# актуальна ли команда execCommand?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, nuxt.js

На Nuxt.js делаю страничку добавления поста

актуальна ли команда execCommand?

как при нажатии enter сделать, чтобы к тегу

добавлялся класс?

document.execCommand('defaultParagraphSeparator', false, "p");

при выделении текста пытаюсь добавить теги, но что-то не работает и не могу понять чего

```
<div class="editor-content" contenteditable="true">
   <p>Тест 2</p>
   <p>Тест</p>
</div>
```

Тулбар для тегов

```
<div class="editor-toolbar__btn editor-toolbar__btn-bold">
   <svg><use href="#bold"></use></svg>
</div>
```

скрипт

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      document.execCommand('defaultParagraphSeparator', false, "p");

    $('body').on('click', '.editor-toolbar__btn-bold', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
    });
    });
    
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если почитать [тут](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_execcommand.asp)

> Примечание. Это экспериментальная технология, которая, вероятно, будет
> изменена до финальной версии.

execCommand()Метод выполняет указанную команду для выбранной части редактируемой секции.

на счет актуальности тут даже не знаю что сказать

Comment: я видел вроде в яндекс дзен при добавлении статьи , но почему-то у меня вообще не работате при клике на выделить жирным

Comment: у меня тут https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_execcommand работает

Comment: и пожалуйста посмотрите на Поддержка браузера

Comment: там не все браузеры поддерживают это